# Symbol container cannot be resolved with different API level

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi so in android studio i changed the Minimum API level of android from 11 to 17 and now I get an error saying that it cannot resolve the symbol container of R. Any help would be great!

Comment: R should be highlight in Red. if you click or hover on it, on the left side you should get a lightbulb, click on that and choose the top/1st  solution you see

Answer (score 0):

First, clean and rebuild your project.

Then, click on "`Sync Project with Gradle Files`" ( on the tabs, the 4 th icon from the right: [image] )

This will fix your problem.

If this is stil not working ( but it should work if everything is fine on your code ), then you have to check on what your IDE is saying: you are probably using deprecated method call, or you might have troubles with a support library as an example.